# Access to the poses in poselib

Tags: python, armature, bones, pose-mode

I have an object with assigned armature .To this armature is assigned poselib, with several poses.Now my intention is to access all of the bones position in my **python script** from the poselib list

I will be very grateful for any hint.

Comment: The same question is already asked over [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/access-to-the-poses-in-poselib/557816) . but no one replied

Comment: I answered, but no upvote yet. What did you mean with "very grateful for any hint"?

Answer (score 0):

A pose library is simply an [Action](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Action.html) datablock. Each pose is actually a [marker](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.TimelineMarker.html) in the `pose_markers` collection; you can use the marker's `frame` property to evaluate the action's `fcurves`, which gives you the pose.